# How to use boost regex_replace with a lambda function?

Tags: c++, boost, lambda

I'm trying to use a lambda function for a call to `boost::regex_replace` on a `std::string` type.  I'm not having luck getting all the types correct.

```
typedef boost::basic_regex<char> regex;
typedef boost::match_results<char> smatch;

    std::string text = "some {test} data";
    regex re( "\\{([^\\}]*)\\}" );
    text  = boost::regex_replace( text, re, [&](smatch const & what) {
        return what.str();
    });
```

*I'm using `typedef` instead of standard names as I have a few places that use a typedef'd/templated character type instead of a fixed type.*

In this code I get this error: `/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/match_results.hpp:68:77: error: no type named 'difference_type' in 'struct boost::re_detail::regex_iterator_traits<char>'
                                     BidiIterator>::difference_type          difference_type;`

Answer (score 4):

If you have a C++11-compliant compiler, you need neither Boost nor lambdas.

To achieve the same goal you can just use [`std::regex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
  std::string text = "some {test} data {asdf} more";
  std::regex re("\\{([^\\}]*)\\}");
  std::string out;
  std::string::const_iterator it = text.cbegin(), end = text.cend();
  for (std::smatch match; std::regex_search(it, end, match, re); it = match[0].second)
  {
    out += match.prefix();
    out += match.str(); // replace here
  }
  out.append(it, end);
  std::cout << out << std::endl;
}
```

Of course, for simple text replacements you can just use `std::regex_replace()` but it's not able to accept a functor, only static format strings, optionally with group placeholders:

```
  std::string text = "some {test} data {asdf} more";
  std::regex re("\\{([^\\}]*)\\}");
  std::string out = std::regex_replace(text, re, "<$1>");
```

Comment: I'll check out this approach (I'm not doing a text replacement, that was just to simplify the example). I guess I've avoided C++ builtin regex so far since I'd have to migrate existing code... or have to regex systems :/

Comment: Thank you! For future readers, note that to replace only the string captured by the parentheses, without the curly braces, the replacement line will look like `out += replace_func(match.str(1));`, with a 1.

Answer (score 3):

As documented [on the match_results reference page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/match_results.html), the first type parameter to `boost::match_results` is the BidirectionalIterator type; so, for example, the standard typedef `boost::smatch` is `match_results<std::string::const_iterator>`.

To fix the code, you need to correct the `smatch` typedef and either remove the reference on lambda parameter `what` or make it a const-reference:

```
typedef boost::basic_regex<char> regex;
typedef boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> smatch;

std::string text = "some {test} data";
regex re("\\{([^\\}]*)\\}");
text = boost::regex_replace(text, re, [] (const smatch& what) {
    return what.str();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with the `smatch` type. I couldn't find a working example with a typename, but using C++14 auto lambda arguments solved the problem:

```
    auto text = "some {test} data";
    regex re( "\\{([^\\}]*)\\}" );
    text  = boost::regex_replace( text, re, [&](auto & what) {
        return what.str();
    });
```